# Can't return my array RGB to change pixel colors

Tags: java

I'm just learning how to use arrays (beginner java user here) and my goal is to turn an image negative by subtracting 255 from the current rgb values of the pixel. My current problem is I don't know how to return the pixel color to the original image. I know I have to use an if statement to control the rgb.
Here is the class that I am using called PixelImage that I imagine I need to modify to change the rgb temporarily for the new image

```
import java.awt.image.*;

/**
 * Provides an interface to a picture as an array of Pixels
 */
public class PixelImage {
    private BufferedImage myImage;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    /**
     * Map this PixelImage to a real image
     * 
     * @param bi
     *            The image
     */
    public PixelImage(BufferedImage bi) {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.myImage = bi;
        this.width = bi.getWidth();
        this.height = bi.getHeight();
    }

    /**
     * Return the width of the image
     */
    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    /**
     * Return the height of the image
     */
    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    /**
     * Return the BufferedImage of this PixelImage
     */
    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return this.myImage;
    }

    /**
         * 
Return the image's pixel data as an array of Pixels. The   first coordinate
 * is the x-coordinate, so the size of the array is [width][height], where
 * width and height are the dimensions of the array
 * 
 * @return The array of pixels
 */
    public Pixel[][] getData() {
        Raster r = this.myImage.getRaster();
        Pixel[][] data = new Pixel[r.getHeight()][r.getWidth()];
        int[] samples = new int[3];

        for (int row = 0; row < r.getHeight(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < r.getWidth(); col++) {
                samples = r.getPixel(col, row, samples);
                Pixel newPixel = new Pixel(samples[0], samples[1],    samples[2]);
            data[row][col] = newPixel;
        }
    }

    return data;
}

/**
 * Set the image's pixel data from an array. This array matches that
 * returned by getData(). It is an error to pass in an array that does not
 * match the image's dimensions or that has pixels with invalid values (not
 * 0-255)
 * 
 * @param data
 *            The array to pull from
 */
public void setData(Pixel[][] data) {
    int[] pixelValues = new int[3]; // a temporary array to hold r,g,b
                                    // values
    WritableRaster wr = this.myImage.getRaster();

    if (data.length != wr.getHeight()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array size does not match");
    } else if (data[0].length != wr.getWidth()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array size does not match");
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < wr.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < wr.getWidth(); col++) {
            pixelValues[0] = data[row][col].red;
            pixelValues[1] = data[row][col].green;
            pixelValues[2] = data[row][col].blue;
            wr.setPixel(col, row, pixelValues);
        }
    }
}

// add a method to compute a new image given weighted averages
}
```

this is the file that I am working on that is suppose to make all rgb values change.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class NegativeFilter implements Filter{
    public void filter(PixelImage pi) {
        int[] pixelValues = new int[3];
            Pixel[][] data = pi.getData();
            for (int row = 0; row < 256; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col< 256; col++) {
                    Pixel temp = data[row][col];
                    pixelValues[0] = data[row + 10][col + 10].red;
                    pixelValues[1] = data[row + 10][col + 10].green;
                    pixelValues[2] = data[row + 10][col + 10].blue;
                    if (pixelValues[0] > 255)
                        pixelValues[0] = 255;
                    if (pixelValues[1] > 255)
                        pixelValues[1] = 255;
                    if (pixelValues[2] > 255)
                        pixelValues[2] = 255;
                    else if (pixelValues[0] < 0)
                        pixelValues[0] = 0;
                    else if (pixelValues[1] < 0)
                        pixelValues[1] = 0;
                    else if (pixelValues[2] < 0)
                        pixelValues[2] = 0;

            }
            }
            pi.setData(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NegativeFilter implements Filter {
public void filter(PixelImage pi) {
    Pixel[][] data = pi.getData();
    for (int row = 0; row < pi.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < pi.getWidth(); col++) {
            // original values of the pixel
            Pixel i = data[row][col];
            int red = i.red;
            int green = i.green;
            int blue = i.blue;
            // creates the inverse by subtracting 255 from the original pixel
            int inverseRed = 255-red;
            int inverseGreen = 255 - green;
            int inverseBlue = 255 - blue;
            i.red = inverseRed;
            i.green = inverseGreen;
            i.blue = inverseBlue;
        }
    }
    pi.setData(data);
}
}
```

Comment: No point in the `pi.setData(data);` at the end, since you never changed the `data` reference.